Bunch of guys get stuck in mud/quicksand/something, sing Internationale
The scene I remember involves a group of middle-aged guys (maybe 5 of them, I believe they were all white but not 100% sure on this) walking through a rural plains-like area. Somehow, they get stuck around waist deep in mud, quicksand, or something like that. They sing the Internationale as the sun sets on them.
I saw it while flipping channels but couldn't stick around to watch it. The vibe struck me as indie but I can't say for sure.
Any ideas?

Can you supply a timeframe? Suspected release date? Any (near)-familiar faces?

Wish I could give a little more. I caught 10 minutes of it tops, but that apparently that little bit was memorable. This was about 5 years ago that I caught this bit, so its no newer than that. If I had to go waaaaay out on a limb, my feeling was that it's a late 90's early 00's American independent film. As far as naming actors, I've got nothing for you whatsoever.

I saw this short film a few years ago and it has always stuck in my mind. 
It is a Norwegian short from 2002 called De Beste Går Først - the English title was United We Stand.
From the IMDb synopsis:
Nine elderly men get together in the backlands to go hiking, as they apparently have for seventy years -- they sing songs like 'The Internationale', long an anthem of socialism -- and find a young woman trapped in a marsh. Making a chain, they get her out and she waves goodbye and goes on her way, while they sink slowly into the earth, singing as they descend.


Yes that's it! Thank you.
